# Whatsapp button working on Android but Blank on IOS

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, whatsapp

This code is working good on android device like Samsung Galaxy Tab and S3 etc. After selecting a contact, it appears `TheTitle -> TheURL`.

But it's not working at iOS device like iPhone 6 plus and iPhone 5. After selecting a contact, the `TheTitle -> TheURL` does not appear, it's just blank.

How can I fix this?

```
var TheTitle = "post Title Text", TheURL = "blog.com/url-post.html";

$('#myID').after('<a class="button-share whatsapp" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" href="whatsapp://send?text=' + TheTitle + ' -> ' + TheURL + '" target="_blank">WhatsApp</a>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Text value must encode at iOs Whatsapp.

```
var TheTitle = "post Title Text", 
    TheURL = "blog.com/url-post.html",
    nuklear = TheTitle + ' ›› ' + TheURL,
    bomb = encodeURIComponent(nuklear);
$('#myID').after('<a class="button-share whatsapp" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" href="whatsapp://send?text=' + bomb + '" target="_blank">WhatsApp</a>');
```

Tested: working on Android and iOS